# python appjar function doesn't thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, python-3.5, python-multithreading

having issues trying to get threading working in python using the awesome [Appjar package](http://appjar.info/).

The following program needs to count through a list, and update a progress bar simultaneously. I've followed the [appjar documentation for threading](http://appjar.info/pythonThreads/), but it's returning `NameError: name 'percent_complete' is not defined` in the `app.thread` (line 35), in which you're meant to insert function params - my code is below:

```
from appJar import gui
import time

# define method the counts through a list of numbers, and updates the progress meter

def press(btn):
    objects = [1,3,6]
    total = len(objects)
    current_object = 0
    for i in objects:
        print(i)
        current_object += 1
        current_percent_complete = (current_object / total) * 100
        updateMeter(current_percent_complete)
        time.sleep(1)

def updateMeter(percent_complete):
    app.queueFunction(app.setMeter, "progress", percent_complete)

# create a GUI variable called app

app = gui("Login Window")
app.setBg("orange")
app.setFont(18)

# add GUI elements : a label, a meter, & a button 

app.addLabel("title", "COUNTER")
app.setLabelBg("title", "blue")
app.setLabelFg("title", "orange")

app.addMeter("progress")
app.setMeterFill("progress", "green")

app.addButton("START COUNTING", press)

# put the updateMeter function in its own thread

app.thread(updateMeter, percent_complete)

# start the GUI

app.go()
```

I can get rid of the error by defining `percent_complete` like so:

```
from appJar import gui
import time

# define method the counts through a list of numbers, and updates the progress meter

percent_complete = 0

def press(btn):
...
```

However, when GUI loads and button is pressed it doesn't thread. Instead it iterates through the list, then updates the progress bar afterwards.

Has anyone come across the same issue? any insight would be awesomely appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

- First, I'm not sure your maths result in good percentages to update the meter with, so you might not see much change - should you be using `i`?
- Second, the GUI won't be updated until the loop (and the sleeps inside it) all complete. Instead, you should try counting how many items to process, and iterating through them with an `after()` function, see here: http://appjar.info/pythonLoopsAndSleeps/#conditional-loops
- Third, the call to `app.thread()` at the end doesn't achieve much - it calls the `update_meter()` function with a parameter that doesn't exist, it can be removed.
- Fourth, the actual `update_meter()` function isn't necessary, as you're not really using a thread - that can be removed as well...

Give this a try, once you've had a look at the maths:

```
current_object = 0
def press(btn):
    global current_object
    current_object = 0
    processList()

def processList():
    global current_object
    objects = [1,3,6]
    total = len(objects)
    if current_object < total:
        i = objects[current_object]
        print(i)
        current_object += 1
        current_percent_complete = (current_object / total) * 100
        app.setMeter("progress", current_percent_complete)
        app.after(1000, processList)
```

---

**UPDATE:** just to clarify on the maths issue, you're dividing one integer by another: 0/3, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3 and so on. In python2 this will result in 0, in python3 you'll get fractions.